# Loop Infinito ao ler valores de Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

O meu objetivo é fazer o depósito em várias notas (10, 20, 50 e 100).
Para isso, no método `main` deixei dessa forma:

```
static Scanner lerInfo = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nOpc = 0;

    while (nOpc != 9) {
        System.out.println("Opções: ");
        System.out.println("1-Depósito");
        System.out.println("2-Saque");
        System.out.println("3-Extrato");
        System.out.println("9-Sair");
        System.out.println("Qual opção deseja?");
        nOpc = lerInfo.nextInt();

        if (nOpc == 1) {

            Deposito deposito = new Deposito();
            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ");
            deposito.setQtdCem(lerInfo.nextInt());
            deposito.setTotalCem(lerInfo.nextInt()*100);
            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CINQUENTA para Depósito: ");
            deposito.setQtdCinq(lerInfo.nextInt());
            deposito.setTotalCinq(lerInfo.nextInt()*50);
            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de VINTE para Depósito: ");
            deposito.setQtdVinte(lerInfo.nextInt());
            deposito.setTotalVinte(lerInfo.nextInt()*20);
            System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de DEZ para Depósito: ");
            deposito.setQtdDez(lerInfo.nextInt());
            deposito.setTotalDez(lerInfo.nextInt()*10);
            // deposito.setTotalNoCaixa(deposito.getTotalCem()+deposito.getTotalCinq()+deposito.getTotalVinte()+deposito.getTotalDez());
            // System.out.println(deposito.getTotalNoCaixa());

        }

        if (nOpc == 2) {
            Saque();
        }
        if (nOpc == 3) {
//          ImprimeExtrato();
        }
        if (nOpc == 9) {
            return;
        }

    }
```

E na classe `Deposito`, deixei assim:

```
package model;

public class Deposito {

    private int qtdCem;
    private int qtdCinq;
    private int qtdVinte;
    private int qtdDez;

    private int totalCem;
    private int totalCinq;
    private int totalVinte;
    private int totalDez;

    private int totalNoCaixa;

    public int getQtdCem() {
        return qtdCem;
    }

    public void setQtdCem(int qtdCem) {
        this.qtdCem = qtdCem;
    }

    public int getQtdCinq() {
        return qtdCinq;
    }

    public void setQtdCinq(int qtdCinq) {
        this.qtdCinq = qtdCinq;
    }

    public int getQtdVinte() {
        return qtdVinte;
    }

    public void setQtdVinte(int qtdVinte) {
        this.qtdVinte = qtdVinte;
    }

    public int getQtdDez() {
        return qtdDez;
    }

    public void setQtdDez(int qtdDez) {
        this.qtdDez = qtdDez;
    }   

    public int getTotalCem() {
        return totalCem;
    }

    public void setTotalCem(int totalCem) {
        this.totalCem = totalCem;
    }

    public int getTotalCinq() {
        return totalCinq;
    }

    public void setTotalCinq(int totalCinq) {
        this.totalCinq = totalCinq;
    }

    public int getTotalVinte() {
        return totalVinte;
    }

    public void setTotalVinte(int totalVinte) {
        this.totalVinte = totalVinte;
    }

    public int getTotalDez() {
        return totalDez;
    }

    public void setTotalDez(int totalDez) {
        this.totalDez = totalDez;
    }

    public int getTotalNoCaixa() {
        return totalNoCaixa;
    }

    public void setTotalNoCaixa(int totalNoCaixa) {
        this.totalNoCaixa = totalNoCaixa;
    }

}
```

O meu problema ocorre (verifiquei através de debug) quando eu faço o primeiro `set`:

```
deposito.setQtdCem(lerInfo.nextInt());
```

Aqui o sistema fica parado, travado, em loop infinito. 
Poderiam, por favor, me auxiliar onde que eu estou errando?
Não dá mensagem de erro nem nada, só fica no loop.

Comment: A função `nextInt()` deve estar esperando por uma entrada (inteiro, no caso). Não seria isso? O `Scanner` fica esperando pelo input...

Comment: Perdão, não tinha copiado essa linha: static Scanner lerInfo = new Scanner(System.in); É apenas uma variável que recebe a entrada.

Comment: Amigo, Scanner fica esperando uma entrada. Se tu não digitares nada, fica parado ali. Não é isso que tu estás vendo?

Comment: Mas, eu estou digitando, Leonardo.

Comment: Adicionei o momento que trava: Opções: 
1-Depósito
2-Saque
3-Extrato
9-Sair
Qual opção deseja?
1
Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: 
7
** E fica travado aqui.

Comment: Quando tu digitas 9, sai do loop?

Comment: Mas, nesse caso, não deveria ir para o próximo println? Se eu utilizo da mesma forma, não sendo chamado via classe externa (tudo dentro da mesma classe), vai que é uma beleza.

Comment: Sim, quando digito 9 sai do loop.

Comment: Onde estão a implementação dos métodos: **setTotalCem(), setTotalCinq(), setTotalVinte(), setTotalDez()**  da classe **Deposito**?

Comment: Estão todas dentro de Deposito mesmo. Não adicionei aqui porque a classe ficaria muito grande. Mas, vou alterar para melhorar.

Comment: @VictorFreidinger, ao digitar o número desejado o seu breakpoint continua parado na linha do método set() ou simplesmente ele some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está chamando [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) duas vezes seguidas:

```
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ");
deposito.setQtdCem(lerInfo.nextInt());
deposito.setTotalCem(lerInfo.nextInt()*100);
```

Cada chamada de [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) vai esperar você digitar algum valor. Ou seja:

1. o programa imprime a mensagem do `println` ("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ")
2. o primeiro `nextInt()` espera você digitar um número (e passa o valor digitado para `setQtdCem`)
3. o segundo `nextInt()` espera você digitar **outro** número (e passa o valor digitado para `setTotalCem`).

Quando chega no passo 3, o programa *parece* que travou/entrou em loop, mas só porque não foi impressa nenhuma mensagem dizendo que outro número deve ser digitado. Mas na verdade o programa está parado porque o `nextInt()` está esperando que você digite algo.

A solução é fazer como o [André Filipe sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/357503/112052): guardar o valor de `nextInt()` em uma variável e usá-la nos dois métodos (`setQtdCem` e `setTotalCem`). Isso evita que sejam pedidos dois valores:

```
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ");
int qtdCem = lerInfo.nextInt();
deposito.setQtdCem(qtdCem);
deposito.setTotalCem(qtdCem * 100);
```

Isso é até melhor, porque o valor deve ser o mesmo nos 2 métodos, caso contrário a classe `Deposito` ficará inconsistente. Usando duas chamadas de `nextInt()`, o valor digitado em cada um pode ser diferente, e aí a classe `Deposito` poderia ficar com 2 notas de cem, mas com o total igual a 500, por exemplo.

---

Falando nisso, não tem porque ter 2 *setters*, um para a quantidade de notas, e outro para o valor total das mesmas. Pois a existência destes métodos permite que você faça coisas como:

```
// como criar um Deposito inconsistente
Deposito d = new Deposito();
d.setQtdCem(1); // 1 nota de cem
d.setTotalCem(500000); // total não corresponde com a quantidade de notas
d.setTotalNoCaixa(0); // total não corresponde com as notas existentes
```

Isso deixa a classe `Deposito` em um estado inconsistente, pois os totais não batem com a quantidade de notas. Para evitar isso, você poderia simplificá-la eliminando os métodos que manipulam os totais, pois os valores destes podem ser calculados a partir da quantidade de notas:

```
// pode apagar os métodos setTotalXXX e deixar apenas estes:

public int getTotalCem() {
    return this.qtdCem * 100;
}

public int getTotalCinq() {
    return this.qtdCinq * 50;
}

public int getTotalVinte() {
    return this.qtdVinte * 20;
}

public int getTotalDez() {
    return this.qtdDez * 10;
}

public int getTotalNoCaixa() {
    return this.getTotalCem() + this.getTotalCinq() + this.getTotalVinte() + this.getTotalDez();
}

// também pode apagar os campos "totalXXX"
```

Sendo assim, seu código poderia apenas chamar os métodos `setQtdXXX`:

```
Deposito deposito = new Deposito();
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ");
deposito.setQtdCem(lerInfo.nextInt());
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CINQUENTA para Depósito: ");
deposito.setQtdCinq(lerInfo.nextInt());
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de VINTE para Depósito: ");
deposito.setQtdVinte(lerInfo.nextInt());
System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de DEZ para Depósito: ");
deposito.setQtdDez(lerInfo.nextInt());
System.out.println("Total: " + deposito.getTotalNoCaixa());
```

Os totais são calculados a partir das quantidades, evitando que um depósito fique inconsistente.

Comment: Obrigado Filipe! Só uma informação, por favor: Caso eu queira armazenar o total, por exemplo, para utilizar em outro depósito, ou até mesmo para fazer algum cálculo no método saque, como devo proceder? Como se fosse Total := Total + valorJaExistente. Obrigado!

Comment: @VictorFreidinger Não entendi bem sua dúvida. Da maneira que está, o total do depósito é um valor que depende exclusivamente da quantidade de cada nota e eu não mudaria o seu valor diretamente. Se quer adicionar mais notas a um depósito, eu sugiro criar métodos como `adicionarNotasDeCem(int quantidade)`, que soma a quantidade de notas à quantidade atual, por exemplo. Vc só mexe com as quantidades, o total é sempre calculado de acordo. Não sei se é essa a sua dúvida, talvez seja o caso de [fazer outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: A ideia seria, eu fiz um depósito (com as notas de 10, 20, 50 e 100) e quero fazer um novo depósito (com mais valores de 10, 20, 50 e 100). Entendo eu que devo manter os valores do primeiro depósito + o valor do segundo depósito. Seria o caso de outra pergunta ?

Comment: @VictorFreidinger Nesse caso, vc pode manter uma lista de depósitos, usando `java.util.List`. Cada vez que criar um novo depósito, você adiciona o depósito na lista. Do jeito que está o código atual, vc cria um depósito dentro do `if` e logo em seguida o descarta. Se não souber trabalhar com listas, dá uma olhada [nesse tutorial](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/collections-framework/). Se ainda sim tiver alguma dúvida específica, sugiro procurar no site, e caso não encontre, faça outra pergunta.

Comment: @VictorFreidinger Só estou sugerindo isso pq a ideia do site é ter perguntas específicas e focadas. Mesmo que as dúvidas sejam sobre a mesma classe, esta pergunta é sobre o funcionamento do `Scanner`, e a outra dúvida que vc tem *parece* ser sobre design do modelo de classes ou como organizar o código para um objetivo específico (pelo que entendi, claro). Usar listas *parece* ser a solução, mas se puder fazer outra pergunta colocando mais contexto (qual o objetivo do código - criar depósitos é o meio, mas qual o objetivo final?), talvez usar listas nem seja a melhor solução

Comment: @@hkotsubo, eu concordo com você. Vou trabalhar em cima das sugestões e, havendo mais dúvidas, volto ao fórum para detalhar melhor. No mais, obrigado pelas orientações.

Comment: +1. Resposta completa. Descreveu tudo bem detalhado do que havia pensado, porém, estive sem tempo pra explaná-la com mais detalhe. Valeu @hkotsubo

Answer (score 3):

Altere o seu código e adicione o valor digitado em uma variável para solucionar o seu problema e evitar a duplicidade da chamada do `Scanner` nos sets() que possuem multiplicador, Ex.`setTotal(lerInfo.nextInt()*[multiplicador])`;

```
if (nOpc == 1) {
    Deposito deposito = new Deposito();
    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CEM para Depósito: ");
    nOpc = lerInfo.nextInt();
    deposito.setQtdCem(nOpc);
    deposito.setTotalCem(nOpc * 100);
    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de CINQUENTA para Depósito: ");
    nOpc = lerInfo.nextInt();
    deposito.setQtdCinq(nOpc);
    deposito.setTotalCinq(nOpc * 50);
    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de VINTE para Depósito: ");
    nOpc = lerInfo.nextInt();
    deposito.setQtdVinte(nOpc);
    deposito.setTotalVinte(nOpc * 20);
    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de cédulas de DEZ para Depósito: ");
    nOpc = lerInfo.nextInt();
    deposito.setQtdDez(nOpc);
    deposito.setTotalDez(nOpc * 10);
    // deposito.setTotalNoCaixa(deposito.getTotalCem()+deposito.getTotalCinq()+deposito.getTotalVinte()+deposito.getTotalDez());
    // System.out.println(deposito.getTotalNoCaixa()); 
}
```